# Not able to call function present in another script

Tags: jquery

I have two script's

**test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    hello();
});
```

**anotherscript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function hello() {
        alert("!"));
    };  
});
```

If `hello()` is called exception is thrown saying hello is undefined. How should i make the call then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move you hello be global fucton.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
}); 

function hello() {
        alert("!");
 };
```

Comment: thanks dmitry it worked!. But i have included anotherscript.js before test.js..it should work don't know the reason.

Comment: There is a typo in your `hello()` `alert("!"));` <=

Comment: @AmarPalsapure Fixed the typo.

Comment: I was referring to OP :) It's in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

include the test.js file where anotherscript.js is included. It will work

Answer (score 1):

Make your `hello()` function global, by doing

**anotherscript.js**

```
function hello() {
    alert("!");
};
```

And then make sure you have included the js files in following order.

1. jQuery core js
2. anotherscript.js
3. test.js

By doing so, when your code inside test.js gets executed the `hello()` function is available.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: That will not solve the problem as the function is declared within the ready-function. hello() will only be available within that function. He needs to make the hello() function global.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call hello function so you will declare anotherscript.js before test.js